# I cannot find the EFI directory ( grub-install ARCH LINUX)

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

So I'm trying to install Arch Linux for the first time

I have little experience with Linux (dabbled around with Ubuntu and Kali)

During my install, I wrote the command

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

this gave me the following lines

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

I scoured the internet for answers and I eventually found a thread on this same issue
the person answering said question responded with the following solutions

```
mount | grep /boot/efi
```

I received nothing from this command and typed

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

hoping it would work, sadly I got the same error
I then typed

```
mount | grep /dev/[efi device]
```

this gave me the error

```
grep: Unmatched [, [^, [:, or [=
```

then I typed

```
mount /dev/[efi device] /mnt
```

this resulted in

```
mount: bad usage
Try 'mount --help' for more information
```

and finally, I typed

```
grub-install --efi-directory=[efi dir]
```

which gave me

```
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of '[efi'
```

could someone be so kind as to help me out?

Comment: For UEFI installs you have to have an ESP - efi system partition. That is FAT32 and 300 to 500MB. Drive also should be gpt partitioned. Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: You're supposed to replace `[efi device]` with the dev node for the partition on your disk that contains the EFI System Partition.